# How to use blueprintjs without Typescript?

Tags: blueprintjs

I am new to React and I just stumbled to amazing Blueprint components. However, I am unable to use it and I am confused by the installation guide. Its quite different from what I am used so far.

Can anyone explain me how to use Blueprint without Typescript?

Comment: Do you use ES6 JavaScript?

Comment: I use ES5 but I am familiar with ES6. However, the instructions on this page (step 3)  http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#components.usage look like nothing I have seen so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply ignore the Typescript parts. Since you are writing a React app, it needs to be compiled through Babel anyways.

I never used Typescript before and also just started to use blueprint a few days ago and was able to use the JSX components completely without any Typescript knowledge.

Just start using it like any other React components you write - or use DIVs with the blueprint CSS classes directly when necessary. Its up to you.